# Changing redirect link every day

Tags: redirect, link, offers

so I am setting up some daily offers on my Magento site, and I would like my front page banner to always redirect to the daily offer.
Is there a way to set a redirect(or something similar) up, so that every day the redirect link changes to my specefic chosen product?

This is for december, so each day there would be a new offer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create an intermediary page (controller action).
Set the link on the banner to that page.
Inside the action for that page check which one is today's offer and redirect to that.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood u want to change your home page banner URL everyday. That will point to some offer page.

1. Create a configuration setting to set the URL.
2. Just link the banner images with that saved link from configuration. You could get the configuration URL value by

   > Mage::getStoreConfig('Your System Configuration Path');

Now just change that URL whenever you want.